# If someone just got well after sickness wats d ruling of janab ghusul

Tags: sex

Assalamualaikum..I hav 3 questions regarding janaba ghusl.

1.If someone male or female got well after not sick for sometime and is scared dat dey may fall sick again if dey  do whole body ghusl can dey do only body wash excluding head ,, after janaba with d nuyyah of purity.

2. D clothes vch v wear after janaba (on vch der is no impurities) can b worn again after taking ghusl of janaba n can perform namaz etc.

3.The Clothes n accessories ( eg: dress earrings,bangles, anklets, bedsheet on vch v had sex etc ) dat we are wearing during having  sex also shd b included while we do ghusl

Answer (score -1):

1.yes ,if you are afraid of getting sick u can leave the whole janaba ghusl and do tayammum.
2.yes u can wear them as long as they clean.remember semen is pure.
3.no they are already clean